# django haystack custom form

Tags: django-haystack

I'm trying to make a custom search form using django haystack, i just modify from haystack's documentation :

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from haystack.forms import SearchForm

class DateRangeSearchForm(SearchForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False)

   def search(self):
        # First, store the SearchQuerySet received from other processing.
        sqs = super(DateRangeSearchForm, self).search()

        # Check to see if a start_date was chosen.
        if self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(pub_date__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date'])

        # Check to see if an end_date was chosen.
        if self.cleaned_data['end_date']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(pub_date__lte=self.cleaned_data['end_date'])

        return sqs
```

to :

```
from django import forms
from haystack.forms import HighlightedModelSearchForm

class CustomSearchForm(HighlightedModelSearchForm):
    title   = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required = False)
    content = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required = False)
    date_added = forms.DateField(required = False)
    post_by = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required = False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()
        if self.cleaned_data['post_by']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['post_by'])
        if self.cleaned_data['title']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['title'])
        if self.cleaned_data['content']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['content'])
        if self.cleaned_data['date_added']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['date_added']) 
        return sqs
```

haystack .urls :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', search_view_factory(view_class = SearchView, form_class = CustomSearchForm), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

when i go to the url, it says : AttributeError at /search/

'CustomSearchForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

can you guys help me? thx

Then i try to comment the search method, but when i submit a word into the custom field, the result is always nothing, only when i submit a word to non-custom field it can gimme the result i want, already tried to understand this all day long, pls help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is a bit old question, but to help others who may be viewing this and wondering the same thing, this is how I got it working in the same situation.

Something along these lines:

```
...
def search(self)
    sqs=super(MyFooSearchForm, self).search()

    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['foo']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(foostuff__exact=self.cleaned_data['foo'])

    return sqs
```

Basically, I added 'self.is_valid and' before self.cleaned_data['']
this got rid of the error for me. Hope this helps.

So,

```
def search(self):
    sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()
    if self.cleaned_data['post_by']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['post_by'])
    if self.cleaned_data['title']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['title'])
    if self.cleaned_data['content']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['content'])
    if self.cleaned_data['date_added']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['date_added']) 
    return sqs
```

would become:

```
def search(self):
    sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()
    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['post_by']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['post_by'])
    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['title']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['title'])
    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['content']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['content'])
    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['date_added']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = self.cleaned_data['date_added']) 
    return sqs
```

There may be a better way to do this, and I'm a relative beginner for django/python but it worked for me.

Comment: Here is a better way, `if isinstance(sqs, EmptySearchQuerySet): return sqs` do it after the `super()` call and remove all the `is_valid()`

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that firstly form.is_valid() is called. data will not be in cleaned state until isvalid() method is called. therefore while validating all fields, it put all fields one by one in its cleaned_data attribute if they are valid as per form definition.. if any field makes is_valid() false then also cleaned_data exist and contains those data which was validated previously.